# python selenium how to copy text of site?

Tags: python, selenium

How to copy text After load the page with `python`  and `selenium` .
the Html code of site is :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" title="Wrap Long Lines">
</head>
<body>
<pre>32 251 305 266 0.992355
    29 216 480 231 0.985983
    152 76 825 92 0.983704
    116 157 871 173 0.982307
    26 181 535 197 0.971898
    26 76 137 138 0.964413
    25 17 682 40 0.961533
    150 99 815 115 0.910050
    101 118 242 142 0.783791
    102 151 144 158 0.676560
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

my code source :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


i=0 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.textdet.com/')

e = driver.find_element_by_id("imagefile")                  
e.send_keys("/home/brm17/Desktop/ProjetFinDetude/image.png")  



button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(., "Download bounding boxes")]')))
button.click()
```

i want to get the text in < pre >...< /pre > 
what should I do ?

Comment: use `mytext = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
print mytext.text`

Answer (score 1):

You are just close to the output and you just need to get the tag which has the text and print the same.
**Example:**
Based on your code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


i=0 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.textdet.com/')

e = driver.find_element_by_id("imagefile")                  
e.send_keys("/home/brm17/Desktop/ProjetFinDetude/image.png") 
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(., "Download bounding boxes")]')))
button.click()
mytext = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/pre')
print mytext.text
```

This will print the content of `pre` tag as text

Comment: Error : `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/pre`

Comment: @J.Drahimce, Are you using Firefox version 46 and above? Selenium webdriver works best if the Firefox version is less than version 46.